# How do I successfully create ordered categorical data from an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data

Here's a dataframe  - 'dist_copy'  - with values I would like to change to categorical.  I've only included one column, but there are additional columns I want to convert as well.

| state | dist_id | pct_free_reduced_lunch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Illinois | 1111 | 80% - 100% |
| Illinois | 1112 | 0 - 20% |
| Illinois | 2365 | 40% - 60% |

`dist_copy.pct_free_reduced_lunch.unique()`

returns

`array(['80% - 100%', '60% - 80%', '0 - 20%', '20% - 40%', '40% - 60%'], dtype=object)`

Previously, I used `pd.Categorical` to change all the values in the 'pct_free_reduced_lunch' column to 'categorical', and established the order, with this code:

```
dist_copy['pct_free_reduced_lunch'] = pd.Categorical(dist_copy['pct_free_reduced_lunch'], 
     categories=['0 — 20%','20% — 40%', '40% — 60%', '60% — 80%',  '80% - 100%'], ordered=True)
```

Today, this code isn't working, and only retains the first value, changing all other values to NaN.

| state | dist_id | pct_free_reduced_lunch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Illinois | 1111 | 80% - 100% |
| Illinois | 1112 | NaN |
| Illinois | 2365 | NaN |

What am I doing wrong, or misunderstanding?

UPDATE:  The above code began to work AFTER I copy-pasted each categorical value from the array returned by `unique()` into the categories array inside the `pd.Categorical` function, in the desired order.

When I merely entered them from scratch, NaNs were created.

WHY?  I would really love to know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using dashes instead of hyphens for you `categories` argument, all but for `'80% - 100%'`. But in the data there are only hyphens and therefore all but `'80% - 100%'` turn into `NaN`.

Try using `categories=sorted(dist_copy.pct_free_reduced_lunch.unique())` to avoid this kind of typo.

Comment: This is why the copy-paste strategy worked!  THANK YOU! Anders, apologies for asking a dumb question--but how did you figure that out?

Comment: Create this category dtype `cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=['0 - 20%','20% - 40%', '40% - 60%', '60% - 80%',  '80% - 100%'], ordered=True)` and apply on all columns you want: `df['pct_free_reduced_lunch'].astype(cat)`

Comment: @JosephShuffield I spotted it in Jupyterlab when copy-pasting your code, they are quite distinguishable there, not so much here on SO.